# Can you change R scripting front-end version in command line?

Tags: r, macos

Currently on my system (macOS Catalina) I installed R 3.6.2, and also installed R in anaconda. However, when I ran `Rscript --version` it says `R scripting front-end version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)`. I am speculating this is the reason why even though I installed a package in RStudio it keeps throwing a segfault and say that this specific package is not installed or obsolete. Is there a way to update the command line Rscript to a later version? How would you do that? Or is this segfault not due to the non-matching R versions?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have 2 different versions of R installed. The on you are reaching through the terminal appears to be different from the one through the GUI.

You will have to do a little bit of detective work to figure out which 2 paths for R you have and which one you want. You can then manipulate the $PATH environment variable in your terminal to get you where you want. For example on my Mac I have the following:

```
which R
# /usr/local/bin/R
ls -lF /usr/local/bin/R
# lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  47 Aug  5 10:11 /usr/local/bin/R@ -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
which Rscript
# /usr/local/bin/Rscript
ls -lF /usr/local/bin/Rscript
# lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  53 Aug  5 10:11 /usr/local/bin/Rscript@ -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript
```

Comment: I see -- I'm sorry this might sound super stupid but... how do you modify the $PATH variable in terminal to change that specific line? I tried `sudo nano /etc/paths` but I don't think that was quite right. :'(

Comment: To see the current value of $PATH, which is an ordered list of directories, type in `echo $PATH`. To add your R path with highest priority, prepend it like this, up to the "bin" part: `export PATH="/my/path/to/where/r/is/installed/bin:$PATH"`. If you want to make the change permanent, add this line to file `~/.bash_profile`.